# Data validation rule that accepts only 16-digit numbers

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-data-validation

In Google Sheets I am trying to create a custom data validation formula for a column.

I only want 16 character values made up entirely of numbers (e.g. 0-9).

I tried using a formula that works for me in Excel but it didn't work in Sheets:

```
=AND(LEN(A2)=16,INT(A2)=A2)
```

Already tried `=AND(LEN(A2)=16,ISNUMBER(A2))`  and change the cell format into **Number** (instead of General) to avoid *1.23457E+15* as an output.
But *the 16th digits always change into 0*.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Set the format of the input range to **Plain Text**. Then set a custom formula validation rule for the range like this:

`=LEN(A2)=LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\d{16}"))`